# Generating a List - nothing happens

Tags: python

i took a piece of code that generates a random gene sequence and i want to put n number of generated sequences into a list. this is what i came up with but i don't get anything when i run it. can somebody help?

```
import random

def generateSequence (n):

    n = input('Enter # of list entries: ')
    L = []
    dna = ["A","G","C","T"]
    for i in range(n):

        random_sequence=''

        for i in range(50):
            random_sequence+=random.choice(dna)

        L.append(random_sequence)

    print(L)
    return(L)
```

my second try before i received answers:

```
import random

def generateSequence (n):

    L = []
    dna = ["A","G","C","T"]
    for i in range(n):

        random_sequence=''

        for i in range(50):
            random_sequence+=random.choice(dna)

        L.append(random_sequence)

    print(L)
    return(L)

b = input('Enter # of list entries: ')    
generateSequence(b)
```

Comment: this was indeed the problem, thanks. i looked for the wrong keywords on google so the other thread didn't show up. however, there is another problem i have with this, so i will edit the whole thing to highlight the problem.

Comment: if you have a new problem, please post a new question. Don't edit an existing question to ask a new one.

Comment: ok, i will edit it back, i was thinking about preventing spamming question. i didn't know that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to actually call the function.

For example, if you put this in a file called main.py

```
import random

def generateSequence (n):

    n = input('Enter # of list entries: ')
    L = []
    dna = ["A","G","C","T"]
    for i in range(n):

        random_sequence=''

        for i in range(50):
            random_sequence+=random.choice(dna)

        L.append(random_sequence)

    print(L)
    return(L)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generateSequence(3)
```

gives me the following output when I run it with `python main.py`

```
Enter # of list entries: 2
['GCTGTCTAAATTCGGCTTCACCTAGAAATGTTCAGATGAAATCCAGATGT', 'ACTAGGCGGTATGTTCAGAGCGAGTCGGCGGTTCCCTGGTGGGACTATCC']
```

**Also, the argument of generateSequence is useless**, because you reset its value in the function with the input call.

**Edit**
For the TypeError, input will give you a str (string). You need an integer  for the range function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) so you will need to convert n first. 
For example `for i in range(int(n))`

Note that this assume that n **can be converted to an integer**. If not, int(n) will raise an exception.
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fefw'`

Comment: i would like to ask what the "3" in generateSequence(3) does. also my code changed a bit, could you look over it and tell me which one makes more sense? the argument is there because the exercise i found said: "Write a function generateSequences that receives an integer n as parameter and returns a list containing n random DNA sequences of length 50."

Comment: Second one make more sense. You get an input and call the function with the input. However, you must be careful about how you use it in the function. Check my answer, I edited the end.

Comment: Converting works, thank you. it runs as i want to now. I'm still a bit curious about the number 3. It doesn't seem to matter what number I enter there (not that it matters to the functionality, but I'm eager to learn). Another question I have is, if this actually is "a function that receives an integer n as parameter" because I'm not sure about that after you said it's useless.

Comment: You're right, the number 3 does not matter because it will be replaced by the input. You give a variable n to the generateSequence function, but just after, you call n = input(..) which will replace the value you gave.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you. am i right in the assumption that the input is irrelevant if i want the function to "receive an integer n as parameter" in a sense that you enter the number when you call the function? edit: ah, so if i want to do exactly as the exercise says i need to leave the input out. well, i think i will stray a bit from that since i find the input more comfortable. thank you a lot, everything works perfectly and i learned a thing or two.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the function definition, the line

```
for i in range(n):
```

should be

```
for i in range(int(n)):
```

because the variable `n` defaults to a string when taking input from the command line through the input function.

Since you defined a function instead of simply creating a script (without a function definition), the following calls the function you have defined when you invoke the file from the command line.:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    generateSequence()
```

Also, `return(L)` can simply be `return L` since you are not returning the result of an expression (or a tuple), just a value.

To make it portable, you can put a shebang line at the beginning.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import random


def generateSequence():

    n = input('Enter # of list entries: ')
    L = []
    dna = ["A", "G", "C", "T"]
    for i in range(int(n)):

        random_sequence = ''

        for i in range(50):
            random_sequence += random.choice(dna)

        L.append(random_sequence)

    print(L)
    return L


if __name__ == "__main__":
    generateSequence()
```